Spring 6 and HttpClientErrorException: 431 Request Header Fields Too Large
I have a code
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "https://blabla.com";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

AccessTokenRequest requestBody = new AccessTokenRequest("abcabc111");

HttpEntity<AccessTokenRequest> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);

AccessTokenResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, AccessTokenResponse.class);

I am running my app on Tomcat 10. My current level of the spring is 6.1.11, java level 17.
For some reason I receive
'org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 431 Request Header Fields Too Large: "The custom error module does not recognize this error."'

I change the config of the tomcat:
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
               maxHttpRequestHeaderSize="65536"
               maxHttpResponseHeaderSize="65536"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               compression="on"
               ... />

but it didn't help. Can someone assist with how to fix that?
I tried to convert do WebClient but for some reason, I have a problem with SSL handshake on the K8S pod
webclient code:
webClient.post() .uri("https://blabla.com")
                                   .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                                   .bodyValue(requestBody)
                                   .retrieve()
                                   .bodyToMono(String.class)
                                   .block();


Obtaining HTTP 413 means that the server can't accept the incoming request, it's not due to the client settings. Can you also configure the server side?
